# PHPUnit doesn't seem to be running Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit, migration

I've got an issue where I'm running some tests in laravel 5.4 via phpunit

I'm using an in memory sqlite database for testing

I've got a test class which i've removed bunch of other stuff from so it effectively looks like

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\User;
use App\Order;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class OrderTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    function can_update_status()
    {
         // This is empty, it fails on this test because its alphabetically the first test in the whole suite.
    }
}
```

I've recently created a new migration which adds the "paid" column

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddStatusToOrders extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('completed');
            $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(0);
            $table->dropColumn('paid');
        });
    }
}
```

However whenever I run this test I get an error saying the paid column doesn't exist - even after a `composer du`

```
PHPUnit 6.0.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...................................E

Time: 10.69 seconds, Memory: 46.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\OrderTest::can_mark_as_paid
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: paid (SQL: update "orders" set "paid" = 1, "updated_at" = 2017-04-05 15:27:11 where "id" = 1)

/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:607
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:477
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:416
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2145
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:768
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:581
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:501
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/app/Order.php:62
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/tests/Unit/OrderTest.php:95

Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: paid

/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:79
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:470
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:640
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:607
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:477
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:416
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2145
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:768
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:581
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:501
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/app/Order.php:62
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/tests/Unit/OrderTest.php:95

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: paid

/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:77
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:470
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:640
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:607
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:477
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:416
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2145
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:768
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:581
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:501
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/app/Order.php:62
/Users/owen/Sites/1st-choice-spares/tests/Unit/OrderTest.php:95
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this would be happening, and how I can resolve it? It might be worth adding I've tried changing the column names etc and the same issue is happening with that

Thanks

## UPDATE

If I comment out the lines in the down migration e.g `$table->dropColumn('paid');`

Then it continues to run - however I'm struggling to understand why the down method would be running before the up has been run?

## Update 2

It seems the above finding was due to the column not getting created in the first place, if i suppress that error, the original error appears that the column doesn't exist - which suggests the migration failed to create it.

Comment: I see the test that fails is Tests\Unit\BasketTest::can_get_quotes can you post this test ?

Comment: It just fails there because BasketTest is alphabetically the first, its nothing in the actual test as i've commented them out. So its like its literally happening after the migration - or the migration isnt even running perhaps

Comment: Laravel documentation says "Dropping or modifying multiple columns within a single migration while using a SQLite database is not supported." Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Hmm I wonder, although I'm not dropping or modifying multiple columns :D I'm adding new ones. but if I hit the issue again I'll try this, for the time being I've retrofitted the old migrations to the new schema as its not in production yet so can just manually re-run them from scratch

Answer (score 17):

According to laravel documentation

> Dropping or modifying multiple columns within a single migration while using a SQLite database is not supported.

And although you not trying to modify or drop multiple columns ,you are trying to drop and create in one single migration and in both cases ALTER TABLE query is executed ,and the problem here is the [limitations of ALTER TABLE query of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11) .

You can separate each statement like this:

```
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('completed');
    });

   Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->boolean('paid')->default(0);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('completed')->default(0);
    });
   Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->dropColumn('paid');
    });
}
```

Comment: This does make logical sense, and will try it out - I will upvote, but wont mark as "the answer" until can confirm! But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Owen you can mark it as the answer, I can confirm.